# Jplit reset specific filter(s)

Tags: javascript

So, i'm using the [jplist](https://jplist.com/) plugin to filter a list of flats and i'd need at some point to reset one (or more) specific filters. Point is, there's no api we can use to control the plugin externally.

Here's the code used for the reset button to reset all filters to default:

```
(function() {
  var d = function(b) {
      b.$control.on("click", function() {
        b.observer.trigger(b.observer.events.unknownStatusesChanged, [!0])
      })
    },
    e = function(b) {
      d(b);
      return jQuery.extend(this, b)
    };
  jQuery.fn.jplist.ui.controls.Reset = function(b) {
    return new e(b)
  };
  jQuery.fn.jplist.controlTypes.reset = {
    className: "Reset",
    options: {}
  }
})();
```

I have to admit that i don't fully get how it works but i've done a quick test with this:

```
jQuery('#some-id-button').on('click', function() {
    b.observer.trigger(b.observer.events.unknownStatusesChanged, [!0])
});
```

And it does reset all filters from a specific element.

Question is, how could i pass some arguments (id, classes) to target specific filters and not all of them?